# POST from external server issue on Laravel

Tags: post, laravel, csrf

I am doing a post from an external server to my Laravel app and it is throwing this exception on `app/filters/policy.php`: `Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException`.

This is my `app/filters/policy.php`:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');

    if (Session::token() != $token)
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

And this is my `app/route.php`:

```
Route::any('webservice', ['uses' => 'WebserverController@postWebservice']);
```

I think it is because the CSRF filter is applied to all routes, but I don't know how to disable it to `/webservice`.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you may try something like this:

```
if(Request::url() != 'http://example.com//webservice') {
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token')
    if (Session::token() != $token) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the best way to do it, but I can't find out any other way to do so. Thanks (: