# Attempting to pass GET or POST data to Laravel commenting application

Tags: php, post, laravel, laravel-4, get

Followed the scotch.io tutorial for the following GitHub application:
https://github.com/scotch-io/laravel-angular-comment-app

After finishing the tutorial, curious if it is possible to pass information via a URL to the intended Laravel application. I asked this question on the site but the responses are slow at best.

Here is my route information...

```
URI: POST api/comments

Name: api.comments.store

Action: CommentController@store
```

Here is my CommentController code:

```
<?php
// app/controllers/CommentController.php

class CommentController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Send back all comments as JSON
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Response::json(Comment::get());
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => Input::get('author'),
            'text' => Input::get('text')
        ));

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Comment::destroy($id);

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }

}
```

The input for this application is a form but I'm interested in logging comments from another source. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it using any library like [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in `php` by submitting a `POST` request with your post data. But in this case, make sure to disable `csrf` filter for that external request to your `store` method or generate a persistent token and keep it to tour side (somewhere, maybe in the database temporarily until the request is made) so if the request is carrying your generated token then you may check it for validation (if needed). Because if you have `csrf` enabled on that method and the request is being made from an external resource without the token (Laravel generates a token automatically for the form when using `Form` class to open a form) then the request can't reach that method.

An example of `cURL` request using `POST` method with post data:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"url of laravel site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Now check the response (`$server_output`). If you need to pass the `csrf` token then you need to add it in the `array` inside `http_build_query`. This is just a basic idea, research more. Also you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876586/741747).